# How to get the charset from a Zend_Mail_Part object?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I am trying to determine the character set of a `Zend_Mail_Part` object (I am reading email). How can I get the `charset` information?

I can get the content-type header by doing this:

```
echo $part->contentType;
# text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

I am willing to parse out the `charset` information if that is the only way. Just trying to look for the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Zend_Mail_Part::getHeaderField:

```
$part->getHeaderField('content-type', 'charset');
```

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Mail_Part.html#Zend_Mail_Part::getHeaderField()

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could figure out how to find the `charset` is by using a regular expression:

```
preg_match('/charset="(.+)"$/', $foundPart->contentType, $matches);
$charset = $matches[1];

if ($charset == 'iso-8859-1') {
    $content = utf8_encode($content);
}
```